# Trying to install Angular 2 Material from npm - unrecognized token in source text

Tags: node.js, powershell, angular, npm

I try the following command from PowerShell (as Administrator)

```
npm install @angular2-material
```

and get the error:

```
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:13
+ npm install  <<<< @angular2-material
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

I've even tried getting just a single A2M component (core) and get the same error:

```
npm install @angular2-material/{core}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
npm: 3.9.5
node: 6.2.2
OS: Win7

**Update:**
I found the following issue on A2M GitHub - seems like it might be an issue with PS.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/297

**Update 2:**
Using cmd instead of PS works.

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question with the information you provided in Update 2. It will help others see the solution if they come across a similar issue.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The @ is making PowerShell treat @angular2-material as a variable.

- You could use cmd.exe (command shell) instead of PowerShell

or

- You could surround the package in quotes: e.g.,  `"@angular2-material"`

Comment: In Powershell @ is the "array operator" and the "Splat operator" - basically, it's telling the shell that you passing a variable  that is a collection values

Answer (score 66):

Try quotes:

```
npm install "@angular2-material"
```

Comment: Most likely it is from powershell, so use with quotes because of the @ symbol    so  `npm install --save "@angular/material" "@angular/cdk"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing `npm install @tailwindcss/typography`.(in vs code terminal) but it gives me the same error. Then I try gitbash terminal and successfully installed it. Hope it helps you.