# Upgrade angular-cli:Unrecognized token in source text while running npm install @angular/cli -g

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm getting below error while running "npm install @angular/cli -g"command in vscode(windows 7)

more:

```
    PS C:\Users\rr\Downloads\jschema> node -v
    v12.13.1
    PS C:\Users\rr\Downloads\jschema> npm -v
    6.13.2
    PS C:\Users\rr\Downloads\jschema> npm install @angular/cli -g
    Unrecognized token in source text.
    At line:1 char:13
    + npm install  <<<< @angular/cli -g
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

Can i get help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to install Angular 2 Material from npm - unrecognized token in source text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040479/trying-to-install-angular-2-material-from-npm-unrecognized-token-in-source-tex)

Comment: it's not related to material, I want to upgrade angular-cli version, means to latest

Comment: the answer is not just about material please  check this article

Comment: The problem is the terminal that you are using to install dependencies. It is interpreting @ as some other thing. Open your project workspace in VS Code and try using its integrated terminal.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoVictordeJesus, by default vscode set to "powershell".now i changed to "node" then it's working fine.

Comment: Glad i could help you. I refined my answer suggesting an alternative terminal, since you are using Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal that you are using to install dependencies (PowerShell) is interpreting @ as a variable. Open your project workspace in VS Code and try using its integrated terminal (which may be a bash terminal) and the command should work.

Also, you could use double quotes like this: `npm install "@angular2-material"` and it should work. Just remember that working with Windows terminal is always a bad idea when it comes to these commands.

I suggest you to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and take advantage of its [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) terminal that comes along with it. Just leave Windows command prompt alone.